# ceph crush map - replication

Tags: rules, ceph, crush

Still somewhat confused how Ceph crush maps work and was hoping someone can shed some light. Here's my osd tree:

```
core@store101 ~ $ ceph osd tree
ID  WEIGHT  TYPE NAME                                UP/DOWN REWEIGHT PRIMARY-AFFINITY 
 -1 6.00000 root default                                                               
 -2 3.00000     datacenter dc1                                                         
 -4 3.00000         rack rack_dc1                                                      
-10 1.00000             host store101                                   
  4 1.00000                 osd.4                         up  1.00000          1.00000 
 -7 1.00000             host store102                                   
  1 1.00000                 osd.1                         up  1.00000          1.00000 
 -9 1.00000             host store103                                   
  3 1.00000                 osd.3                         up  1.00000          1.00000 
 -3 3.00000     datacenter dc2                                                         
 -5 3.00000         rack rack_dc2                                                      
 -6 1.00000             host store104                                   
  0 1.00000                 osd.0                         up  1.00000          1.00000 
 -8 1.00000             host store105                                   
  2 1.00000                 osd.2                         up  1.00000          1.00000 
-11 1.00000             host store106                                   
  5 1.00000                 osd.5                         up  1.00000          1.00000
```

I'm simply trying to make sure that, with a replication value of 2 or more, all replicas of an object are not in the same datacenter. The rule I had (taken from the internet) is:

```
rule replicated_ruleset_dc {
        ruleset 0
        type replicated
        min_size 1
        max_size 10
        step take default
        step choose firstn 2 type datacenter
        step choose firstn 2 type rack
        step chooseleaf firstn 0 type host
        step emit
}
```

However, if I dump the placement groups, straight off I see two osd's from the same datacenter. osd's 5,0

```
core@store101 ~ $ ceph pg dump | grep 5,0
1.73    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   active+clean    2015-07-09 13:41:36.939197  0'0 96:113  [5,0]   5   [5,0]   5   0'0 2015-07-09 12:05:01.854945  0'0 2015-07-09 12:05:01.854945
1.70    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   active+clean    2015-07-09 13:41:36.947403  0'0 96:45   [5,0]   5   [5,0]   5   0'0 2015-07-09 12:05:01.854941  0'0 2015-07-09 12:05:01.854941
1.6f    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   active+clean    2015-07-09 13:41:36.947056  0'0 96:45   [5,0]   5   [5,0]   5   0'0 2015-07-09 12:05:01.854940  0'0 2015-07-09 12:05:01.854940
1.6c    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   active+clean    2015-07-09 13:41:36.938591  0'0 96:45   [5,0]   5   [5,0]   5   0'0 2015-07-09 12:05:01.854939  0'0 2015-07-09 12:05:01.854939
1.66    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   active+clean    2015-07-09 13:41:36.937803  0'0 96:107  [5,0]   5   [5,0]   5   0'0 2015-07-09 12:05:01.854936  0'0 2015-07-09 12:05:01.854936
1.67    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   active+clean    2015-07-09 13:41:36.929323  0'0 96:33   [5,0]   5   [5,0]   5   0'0 2015-07-09 12:05:01.854937  0'0 2015-07-09 12:05:01.854937
1.65    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   active+clean    2015-07-09 13:41:36.928200  0'0 96:33   [5,0]   5   [5,0]   5   0'0 2015-07-09 12:05:01.854936  0'0 2015-07-09 12:05:01.854936
1.63    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   active+clean    2015-07-09 13:41:36.927642  0'0 96:107  [5,0]   5   [5,0]   5   0'0 2015-07-09 12:05:01.854935  0'0 2015-07-09 12:05:01.854935
1.3f    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   active+clean    2015-07-09 13:41:36.924738  0'0 96:33   [5,0]   5   [5,0]   5   0'0 2015-07-09 12:05:01.854920  0'0 2015-07-09 12:05:01.854920
1.36    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   active+clean    2015-07-09 13:41:36.917833  0'0 96:45   [5,0]   5   [5,0]   5   0'0 2015-07-09 12:05:01.854916  0'0 2015-07-09 12:05:01.854916
1.33    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   active+clean    2015-07-09 13:41:36.911484  0'0 96:104  [5,0]   5   [5,0]   5   0'0 2015-07-09 12:05:01.854915  0'0 2015-07-09 12:05:01.854915
1.2b    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   active+clean    2015-07-09 13:41:36.878280  0'0 96:58   [5,0]   5   [5,0]   5   0'0 2015-07-09 12:05:01.854911  0'0 2015-07-09 12:05:01.854911
1.5 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   active+clean    2015-07-09 13:41:36.942620  0'0 96:98   [5,0]   5   [5,0]   5   0'0 2015-07-09 12:05:01.854892  0'0 2015-07-09 12:05:01.854892
```

How do I get ensure that at least one replica is alwasy in another dc?

Answer (score 0):

I changed my ceph crush map yesterday:

    `ID  WEIGHT    TYPE NAME           UP/DOWN REWEIGHT PRIMARY-AFFINITY
 -1 181.99979 root default
-12  90.99989     rack rack1
 -2  15.46999         host ceph0
  1   3.64000             osd.1        up  1.00000          1.00000
  0   3.64000             osd.0        up  1.00000          1.00000
  8   2.73000             osd.8        up  1.00000          1.00000
  9   2.73000             osd.9        up  1.00000          1.00000
 19   2.73000             osd.19       up  1.00000          1.00000
...
-13  90.99989     rack rack2
 -3  15.46999         host ceph2
  2   3.64000             osd.2        up  1.00000          1.00000
  3   3.64000             osd.3        up  1.00000          1.00000
 10   2.73000             osd.10       up  1.00000          1.00000
 11   2.73000             osd.11       up  1.00000          1.00000
 18   2.73000             osd.18       up  1.00000          1.00000
...
rack rack1 {
        id -12          # do not change unnecessarily
        # weight 91.000
        alg straw
        hash 0  # rjenkins1
        item ceph0 weight 15.470
        ...
}
rack rack2 {
        id -13          # do not change unnecessarily
        # weight 91.000
        alg straw
        hash 0  # rjenkins1
        item ceph2 weight 15.470
        ...
}
root default {
        id -1           # do not change unnecessarily
        # weight 182.000
        alg straw
        hash 0  # rjenkins1
        item rack1 weight 91.000
        item rack2 weight 91.000
}
rule racky {
        ruleset 3
        type replicated
        min_size 1
        max_size 10
        step take default
        step chooseleaf firstn 0 type rack
        step emit
}`

Please show your "root default" section

And try this

`rule replicated_ruleset_dc {
        ruleset 0
        type replicated
        min_size 1
        max_size 10
        step take default
        step chooseleaf firstn 0 type datacenter
        step emit
}`